# New iPhone 7 Plus does not let me restore a previous backup upon setup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I got a brand new (i.e. sealed) iPhone 7 Plus without simlock. When I turned it on it asked me for my Wifi password, activated itself, asked me to login to my iCloud account and configured itself as a new iPhone.

The *Apps & Data* screen, where I [can choose to restore a backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201269#icloud) as never shown. As it came with iOS 10 preinstalled I assumed I had to upgrade the device in order to use this functionality. Nope. Even with iOS 11, whenever I configure it (i.e. after choosing "Erase all content and settings") it won't display that particular screen.

Any idea what the reason might be? I'm coming from an iPhone 5c and made an iCloud backup which I want to restore on the new iPhone 7 Plus.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the iPhone 7 Plus to your Mac/PC and using iTunes?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes, but the "restore" options is grayed out. Might be an issue with my computer, though.

Comment: Do you see any iCloud backups in your iCloud storage? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215#findiCloud

Comment: @Kelly yes I do

Comment: Can you check if the iPhone is on iOS 11.0 or 11.0.1 (and update to 11.0.1 if needed)? If you did need the update, try the erase all content and settings again and see if you get the Apps & Data screen now.